# Char em c problema

Tags: c, char

Boa noite malta estou aqui com um problema que automaticamente o meu valor é lido no else() alguem sabe porque que isso esta a acontecer? não consigo encontrar o erro.

```
       if((con1 != 0) && (con2 != 0) && (con3 != 0) && (con4 != 0) && (con5 != 0))
{
    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nJa usou todas as opçoes quer continuar ? : ");
    scanf("%c", &opt);

    if((opt == 's'))
    {
         system("cls");
    }

    else if((opt == 'n'))
    {
       return 0;
    }

    else{
        printf("\nErro, introdusa outra vez : ");
        scanf("%c", &opt);
    }

    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não dá para afirmar com certeza apenas com este trecho de código mas, parece, que é o velho problema do buffer de entrada sujo. Garanta que não sobre nenhum caractere no buffer de entrada antes deste seu scanf.Veja o ietm 12.26b de http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/faq/

Comment: basicamente tenho de usar este codigo?

Comment: while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
   /* discard */ ;

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente resolvi o meu problema adicionando mais um scanf

```
       if((con1 != 0) && (con2 != 0) && (con3 != 0) && (con4 != 0) && (con5 != 0))
           {
printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------");
printf("\nJa usou todas as opçoes quer continuar ? : ");
scanf("%c", &opt);
scanf("%c", &opt);

if((opt == 's'))
{
     system("cls");
}

else if((opt == 'n'))
{
   return 0;
}

else{
    printf("\nErro, introdusa outra vez : ");
    scanf("%c", &opt);
}

}
```

Comment: Considerando que você pode assegurar que o caractere que ficou no buffer de entrada é um '\n" acho que ficaria mais simples fazer `scanf(" %c", &opt);`, note o espaço antes do %c que consome o '\n'.